# MVC Grid Custom Binding(Ajax) GroupBy Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using [**telerik grid for mvc with ajax custom binding**](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custombinding) and its running ok, but the problem is when i apply the grouping it sends it ruins the grid.

## Before Grouping

[image]

## After Grouping

[image]

The client side code looks like

```
colums.Bound(o => o.TO).Title("To").Groupable(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).Width(150);
                colums.Bound(o => o.CanChange).Hidden(true);
                colums.Bound(o => o.PlanHospitalID).Hidden(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "planhospital" });
                if ((Model.GeoLocationType == SalesEnum.Region.ToString()))
                {
                    colums.Bound(o => o.RMAcompanies).Groupable(false).Title("Join(RM)").ClientTemplate("<input class='rmjoin' name='RMID' type='checkbox' value='" + Model.DesignationID + "'  <#=RMAcompanies? checked='checked' : '' #>    <#=CanChange? '' : disabled='disabled' #>  /><input type='hidden' name='PlanHospitalID' value='<#= PlanHospitalID#>'/>");
                }
                colums.Bound(o => o.SMCanChange).Hidden(true);
                if (Model.GeoLocationType == SalesEnum.Zone.ToString())
                {
                    colums.Bound(o => o.SMAcompanies).Title("Join(SM)").Groupable(false).ClientTemplate("<input class='smjoin' type='checkbox' name='SMID' value='" + Model.DesignationID + "' <#= SMAcompanies?checked='checked':'' #> <#=SMCanChange? '' : disabled='disabled' #> /><input type='hidden' name='PlanHospitalID' value='<#=PlanHospitalID#>'/>");
                }
                colums.Bound(o => o.Participants).Groupable(false);
```

Comment: Did you implement the grouping in your controller? The online demo shows what needs to be done.

Comment: @AtanasKorchev yes i have implemented the grouping at the server side

Comment: It looks as if groups are not serialized at all. Show us how the controller looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I hava been in the trouble for several days.
I got the cause now...

For the ajax controller, you must:
1--retrieve and send back all the data, not only the pagesize;
2--return the View(model) not the json format.

Hope it can help you out.